# Strange remote desktop connections after Windows 11 startup

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-11

Recently I have noticed that when I start Windows, just after startup, before doing anything or starting any other application, I always have 3 remote desktop processes in the task manager (screenshot below).

[image: Task manager showing 3 unexpected remote desktop processes]

If I try to kill them, immediately another remoted desktop process with different PID spawns, and I end up with 3 unexpected processes again.

Could this be some kind of backdoor or something malicious, or is it normal Windows 11 behaviour?

I've searched through the Internet, and have found [more people with this problem](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-11/remote-desktop-connection-at-start-of-windows-11/m-p/3299378) but no explanation or solution.

I've checked remote desktop connections are not allowed:

[image: Remote desktop configuration screenshot]

but I am not sure it is working, because in Configuration > Privacy and security > For programmers a setting appears checked which reads "Change configuration to allow remote connections to this computer":

[image: For programmers remote desktop setting]

When I enter this section of the configuration it is checked and if I try to uncheck it the "Apply" button below becomes disabled, so I can't change it.

Any clue?

**Edit**

I provide more details on the unexpected processes. Checking who is the parent process I've found the same pattern for all unexpected remote desktop processes (only interesting lines of the output shown):

```
PS C:\Users\> wmic process get Caption,ParentProcessId,ProcessId
Caption                          ParentProcessId  ProcessId
svchost.exe                      1032             16008
wslhost.exe                      16008            8864
conhost.exe                      8864             6476
mstsc.exe                        8864             19292
```

So, the process tree is svchost > wslhost > mstsc. My question then is why is Windows Subsystem for linux launching remote desktop processes?

I can confirm the connections do disappear if I do `wsl --shutdown`.

Comment: To clarify, your "Remote connections are not allowed" screenshot is about _inbound_ connections (i.e. acting as an RDP server). It has absolutely no effect on _outbound_ connections (MSTSC is an RDP _client_ that connects to other machines).

Comment: Aside from that, I _suspect_ this has something to do with WSLg, i.e. the graphical application support in WSL2 (which is pretty much RDP-based RemoteApp adapted for local use), but it's not something I could investigate myself (I cannot install WSL2 here for various reasons).